# Saving textured GLB file in trimesh

Tags: python, gltf, 3d-modelling, trimesh

I am trying to save a textured OBJ file as a GLB. The texturing imports fine, i can see it using `mesh.show()`, but when i export as a GLB no texture appears on the model. I saw another similar [issue](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/issues/523) on github that makes it seem as if this has been implemented but it doesnt seem to be working here.

Thanks so much!!

```
mesh = trimesh.load("models/all/odm_texturing/odm_textured_model_geo.obj")  
mesh.show()  
mesh.export(file_type="glb", file_obj="output/landslide.glb")
```

`mesh.show():`

[image]

After export:
[image]

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: I avoided it by using the incredibly ugly solution of running blender headless and doing the processing there